# How to redact or hide a substring in a string in C

Tags: c, string, replace

In C, how to redact or hide a substring such as "password" in a longer string such as "Hello password", replacing it with an arbitrary character such as '*' (repeated as necessary to fill in the substring)?

Here is the intended usage for such a function, called `redact`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "Hello password";
    printf("Input:\t\"%s\"\n", s);
    redact(s, "password", '*');
    printf("Output:\t\"%s\"\n", s);
}
```

Expected results:

> Input:  "Hello password"
>
> Output: "Hello ********"

Note: there are more general solutions involving replacement strings of arbitrary length and additional memory allocation that would not be as efficient for this special case:

- [Remove a substring from a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116974/remove-a-substring-from-a-string-in-c)
- [Replace all occurrences of a substring in a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413667/replace-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-a-string-in-c)

Comment: I've amended both the title and the body of the question to clarify the intended language.

Comment: I've copied some of my answer into my question. I'm trying to satisfy the expected format. I came here to pose a specific question to a common problem and to offer a succinct answer superior to that found in related posts.

Comment: I see that you added your code now which is good.  I added the missing header and reinserted the C tag.

Comment: Thank you for your edits! Let me know if you see any further changes need to make the question more focused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation of such a function `redact`:

```
// redact or hide a (repeated) substring, in place
// <https://stackoverflow.com/a/76592815/2103990>
bool redact (char *haystack, char *needle, char c) {
    char *p = strstr(haystack, needle);
    if (p == NULL)  return false;
    memset(p, c, strlen(needle));
    return redact(haystack, needle, c);
}
```

Bonus: it accounts for repetitions in the search substring:

> Input:  "Hello password password"
>
> Output: "Hello ******** ********"

Demonstration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

bool redact (char *haystack, char *needle, char c);

int main()
{
    char s[] = "Hello password password";
    printf("Input:\t\"%s\"\n", s);
    redact(s, "password", '*');
    printf("Output:\t\"%s\"\n", s);
}

// (paste function redact here)
```

Comment: Why `strcpy` into `s` to initialize it when you could simply initialize it with `char s[100] = "Hello password";`?  You also do not need to separately declare and initialize `t`, nor does returning it from `main` but not otherwise using it make much sense.

Comment: @Chris thanks for your suggestions, I've simplified the demo; the actual answer is function redact.